# Should I commit to ISTQB Test automation certification?

Tags: quality-assurance, career-development

I am a test automation engineer. I already hold Foundation level. I am considering to advance in ISTQB certification. My ultimate goal is to become expert in testing including all aspects (testing practices and decision taking processes). So, roles as test leader/manager are in my agenda, but I want to do more test automation.
Question is whether it is worth to take "Test automation certification" before advancing my testing career as "Test manager" or "Test leader".

Note: I find the knowledge gathered in Foundation certification books very valuable. When answering please do not relate certification to a piece of paper, instead a way to dig into specific testing area.

Comment: Flagged as duplicate, question essentially boils down to the same.

Comment: The answer to this question is "primarily opinion-based", so I voted to close it. My opinion is ISTQB stuff is just a piece of paper. ;-)